# cPath not being built correctly in zen cart

Tags: php, zen-cart

hi I am having and issue with my cPath being built when viewing product info pages from anywhere other than directly following the path of the categories. I am only getting the master_category_id in the url instead of the full path.

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an SEO module enabled on your ZenCart installation, such as MagicSEO? In my experience these modules do have an uncontrollable impact on the cPath derivation and parameters in the constructed URL.

Notwithstanding the above, I am unclear what you would expect ZenCart to do when a user clicks a link to one of your products, where the link is not via the drilled down category structure. ZenCart will have no choice but to derive the cPath from the Master Category for the product, as it will not know which one of potentially many category paths to derive.